# App Uses Debug Environment URL In Production

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have an app that is produced using Fastlane and TestFlight. I use BugSnag for bug reports and I have come across a bug recently with all of my builds.

```
RCTFatalException: Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed out. Are you running node proxy? If you are running on the device, check if you have the right IP address in `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`._mh_execute_header
```

That being said, I have never had this problem before in which it attempts to load development URL in production... here is my `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
#import <BugsnagReactNative/BugsnagReactNative.h>


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  // lets try initializing it before the app loads.
  [BugsnagReactNative start];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Dropday"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


  [FIRApp configure];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];


  return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging willPresentNotification:notification withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
  [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

@end
```

I am somewhat unsure of how to proceed in debugging or resolving this problem, any help is greatly appreciated. I have re-deployed my application multiple times with no success either.

EDIT: Turns out to be a bug on the client side. I had to completely remove the app and re-install to get it working again. Not sure why this happens, maybe RN devs could have some insight?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BugsnagAPIKey</key>
    <string>556d85b64984c82022f674abcbc4db4b</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Dropday</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>me.cameronb.dropday.app</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.11</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Access photos to send to other group members.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto_medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto.ttf</string>
        <string>rubicon-icon-font.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you show your info.plist? I think your ATS is wrong or app is not in debug mode

Comment: If you are sure this is a bug, I think its better if you open up an issue on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues) and notice the devs and contributors about it. There is also a bigger chance of you getting a faster response.

Comment: @blacksun Added the requested file